# how to route my blade file in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working with Laravel app. I need route collaborator.blade.php file in projects folder in view file. I have following form and after fill form data and save it need redirect it to collaborator.blade.php file. My form working with project controller

```
 $project = new Project;
        $project->project_name   = $request->input('name');
        $project->project_status = $request->input('status');
        $project->group          = $request->input('group');
        $project->color          = $request->input('color');
        $project->project_notes  = $request->input('notes');
        $project->user_id        = Auth::user()->id;

        $duplicate = Project::where('project_name',$project->project_name)->first();
        if($duplicate)
        {
            return redirect()->route('projects.index')->with('warning','Title already exists');
        }   

        $project->save();

        return redirect()->route('projects.collaborators')->with('info','Your Project has been created successfully');
    }
```

but when I click form button system occured an error message like this.

```
Route [projects.collaborators] not defined.
```

how can fix this problem?
edited 
new routes

```
Route::get('/collaborators', function(){
    return view('projects.collaborators');
});
```

then occurred following error messages

```
Route [projects.collaborators] not defined.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `route` name, if I see it right you can try this :

`Route::get('/collaborators', function(){
    return view('projects.collaborators');
})->name('yourroutename');`

and then you can call the route like :

`return redirect()->route('yourroutename');`

Answer (score 0):

Just create a route in `App/Http/routes.php` that points to your `collaborator.blade.php`and name it `projects.collaborators`

```
Route::get('/collaborators', function(){
    return view('collaborator.blade.php');
})->name('projects.collaborators');
```

Comment: the route needs to be in `routes.php`which can be found in your laravel root directory under `app/Http` see https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.2/app/Http/routes.php